# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Class Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my feeble attempt to write better Model methods, I am failing hard. Which in turn, has brought me to ask my question here.

Here is my Model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Because of inheritance issues with ActiveRecord
  # We tell this Relation to use a "false" column to persuade
  # The relation to push forward without worrying about Inheritance
  self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled

  scope :expired?, where('expiration_date > ?', Time.now)
end
```

This is what I am trying to do with my `scope`

```
g = Group.find(91)
g.expired?
```

So, essentially see if I can tell if the group is expired. Now, I know I can write this in my controller in my activerecord where statement, but I am trying to better understand handling data in models with `Rails`

Comment: By the way, the expired? condition should be "where('expiration_date < ?', Time.now)" I think. (i.e. less-than 'now')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what scopes are for ;)

To do what you want, just add an instance method:

```
def expired?
    expiration_date > Time.now
end
```

An `expired` scope would be use to select expired groups:

```
scope :expired, lambda { where('expiration_date > ?', Time.now) }
```

And you would use it like that:

```
Group.expired
# or
user.groups.expired
#etc
```

Comment: Wow, this is so eye opening. Thanks for the explanation! So, Rails will automatically pick up the `expiration_date` as a piece of the object and will use it in the evaluation comparison? I come from a PHP background, where this IS NOT anywhere close to being possible (will not this easy)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can understand from your `g.expired?` you're looking for an *instance method* and for this very reason you can use [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes). It serves a different purpose. So, if you really want an instance method you should do something like:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base

  def expired?
    self.expiration_date > Time.now
  end
end
```

By the way, if you want, say, all the expired groups you were on the right path with scope. But be aware of the fact you need a lambda to properly evaluation the query:

```
scope :expired, lambda { where('expiration_date > ?', Time.now) }
```